# What does $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ mean in induction?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, induction

If you're given that 
 $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

and let's say that prove that
 $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+\frac{1}{k+n}=blah$, $n>0$ what does $k$ in itself equal? I mean if you had to put $k$ in $n$ terms.

PS - the exact question is different but I need to understand the idea of it to apply it to the actual question.

Comment: Not sure I get the question.  If, say, $n=3$ then $\sum_{k=1}^3 \left( k+\frac 1k\right) = 1+\frac 11 +2 +\frac 12+ 3 +\frac 13$.

Comment: @lulu I just edited the question to make it more legible. I just want to know how to get $k$ in terms of $n$ for induction proof.

Comment: "*what does $k$ equal?*"  $k$ is the *indexing variable* which begins at the stated lower bound (in this case $1$) and increases by $1$ until reaching the upper bound (in this case $n$), and since we are using the summation symbol this implies we add up all of the results.  The "summands" are the terms actually being added (in your first problem, $k$, in your second problem $k+\frac{1}{k+n}$).

Comment: There is no "expressing $k$ in terms of $n$" to be done here.  $k$ is each and every one of the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,\dots,n\}$ at different times.

Comment: So let's say that you need to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(n-k)=\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{6}$, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  As many have pointed out, you can not "get $k$ in terms of $n$" as $k$ is just the indexing variable.  As to closed formulas for sums...Sometimes sums like these have closed forms, sometimes they don't.  Sometimes they are easy to prove, sometimes they are not.  There isn't any sort of "one size fits all" result.

Comment: "*lets say you need to prove... how would you go about doing that*" as should be heavily implied by what unit you are currently studying, I would do it with *induction*.  Suppose I want to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(k,n)=g(n)$.  I would first prove it is true that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^1f(k,1)=g(1)$, and then by assuming that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell f(k,\ell)=g(\ell)$ for *some* $\ell\geq 1$ use that information to prove that it follows that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\ell +1}f(k,\ell +1)=g(\ell+1)$ must also be true, thereby proving the statement true for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: For example, if you wish to prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, first check it is true for when $n=1$.  Indeed $\sum\limits_{k=1}^1 k = 1 = \frac{1(1+1)}{2}$, so it is true then.  Next, assume it is true for some $\ell$ in place of $n$.  Finally, for $\ell+1$ instead we have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\ell+1} k = \ell+1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell k$ which by our induction hypothesis the sum on the right simplifies: $\ell+1+\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2}$ which after a bit of algebraic manipulation is $\frac{(\ell+1)((\ell+1)+1)}{2}$, exactly as we hoped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get "$k$" in terms of $n$ seeing as $k$ is an indexing variable as already pointed out. I think you want to get a closed form of your partial sum in terms of $n$. In which case, there's really no catch-all trick to do this for any partial sum. For this particular one, you can split the sum since it's a finite sum into
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i + \frac{1}{i+n}) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} j + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+n}$$
and you already know what $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j$ equals.

Now we just want to find a closed form for the rightmost sum. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a closed form for this sum.

In general, what I'd try first for these problems is guessing a closed form then proving it by induction after plugging in some values of $n$, or I'd try to work with the terms (e.g. slick telescoping sum tricks). There are other methods out there (e.g. Abel's summation formula).

Answer (score 2):

In such a sum ($\sum_{k=1}^n$k), which simply means $1+2+\dots+n$, $\;k$ is a `dummy` variable, i.e. a temporary counter which is incremented at each step of the calculation of the sum, and  allows us to control at which step we have arrived. As all dummy variables the final result does NOT depend on $k$, and you may very well replace it with another letter without changing the final result.

You can find a similar situation in the notation for a definite integral:
for instance, in the equality  $\;\int_0^1 x^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac13$, the left-hand side does NOT depend on $x$, which is a dummy variable.

Comment: I think you meant a different sum.

Comment: @JannikPitt: Oh! yes. I forgot to check for any mistyping. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: If you meant the sum to be equal to $1+2+3+...+n$, then there has to be a $k$ inside the sum.

Comment: It is not necessary: this is an informal notation that everyone understands. Let's say $k$ is represented by the dots.

Comment: He is referring to you need a $k$ in $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\color{red}{k}$.  Without that red $k$, someone might interpret it as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\color{red}{1}$ which simplifies to $n$ instead of to $\binom{n+1}{2}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I seem to have misunderstood what he meant. As you know, it's easier to see other people typos :o) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think this is just one of those things where a lightbulb needs to go off in your head. You usually can't explain this kind of symbolism to someone unless they're willing to blindly accept a list of arbitrary rules and then follow the rules. But this kind of explanation only comes easy if the asker has done it before. There's a boot-strap that must happen here. And no one can do it for you the first time.

The best we can do is explain by example. There is a pattern to the list of equations underneath. You have to find it. The $k$ is not important.
\begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^n k &=1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)+n\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 &=1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots +(n-1)^2+n^2\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 &=1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots +(n-1)^3+n^3\\
\sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1) &=(2\cdot 1+1)+(2\cdot 2+1)+(2\cdot 3+1)+\cdots+(2(n-1)+1)+(2n+1)\\
\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1) &=(1+1)+(2+1)+(3+1)+\cdots +((n-1)+1)+(n+1)\\
\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) &=f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\cdots +f(n-1)+f(n)
\end{align*}